# Share database connection among multiple routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've created an extremely simple [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) app based on [Express](http://expressjs.com/)'s [route-separation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-separation/index.js) example. I want to power this app with the [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) driver [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). This example just lists `Users` and `Kittens`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var user = require('./user');
var kitten = require('./kitten');

// Connect MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongoose');

// Express config here
...

// User
app.all('/users', user.list);

// Kitten
app.all('/kittens', kitten.list);

// Mongoose connection
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function callback () {
  var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
});

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Express started on port 3000');
}
```

To me it seems it would be wise to connect to the Mongo database on startup rather than for each request.

But how do I share that Mongoose connection with both the `user` and `kitten` routes? I know if I didn't need to share the connection between the two, I could just connect to the database in my `user.js` and `kitten.js` code.

Answer (score 2):

In `node.js` when you do `require` a file, you run the code in that file **exactly once**. Which means you can store things through closure.

foobardb.js

```
(function(){
  "use strict"; // always nice to have

  var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      databaseConnection; 

  module.exports = function() {

      if ( !databaseConnection ) {
           mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongoose')
           databaseConnection = mongoose.connection;
      }

      (...)
  };

})();
```

The `databaseConnection` will be shared with all the `require("foobardb.js");` you do